# docker build error in Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, docker

When I try to run 'docker build .' or 'docker build - < Dockerfile', errors appeared as below:

```
[root@VM_60_90_centos dtask-ctrip-train-domestic]# docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 38.98 MB 
Step 1 : FROM ubuntu:14.04  ---> 132b7427a3b4 
Step 2 : MAINTAINER Ke Peng<ke.peng@jingli365.com>  ---> Using cache  ---> 
         db9529465f77 
Step 3: WORKDIR /opt/app  ---> Using cache  ---> 3122f40a8e56 
Step 4 :COPY . ./  ---> 4d67a5fbf128 Removing intermediate container
c2d83602f613 
Step 5 : RUN npm  install  ---> Running in 67680232cbdf

/bin/sh: 1: npm: not found The command '/bin/sh -c npm  install'
returned a non-zero code: 127
```

and my Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04 
MAINTAINER Ke Peng <ke.peng@jingli365.com> 
WORKDIR /opt/app 
COPY . ./ 
RUN npm  install 
COPY dist/ /opt/app/ 
CMD node ./index.js < test.json
```

Can anyone have similar experience and give me an solution. Very appreciated!

Comment: That docker image maybe doesn't have nodejs

Comment: you need to install NPM in the machine.

Comment: when i execute npm -v and node -v, I can see the version info in centos operating system. It seems there is no npm in docker images, but how should i do

Comment: May I add that MAINTAINER is deprecated, use LABEL instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the base image to [one containing node](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/), such as:

```
FROM node:6
MAINTAINER Ke Peng <ke.peng@jingli365.com> 
WORKDIR /opt/app 
COPY . ./ 
RUN npm  install 
COPY dist/ /opt/app/ 
CMD node ./index.js < test.json
```

Note: changed the first line only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04 
MAINTAINER Ke Peng <ke.peng@jingli365.com> 
RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN sudo -y apt-get install nodejs
RUN sudo -y apt-get install npm
WORKDIR /opt/app 
COPY . ./ 
RUN npm  install 
COPY dist/ /opt/app/ 
CMD node ./index.js < test.json
```

Edited as suggested in comments

Comment: No, not working, infors like :103 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 49.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 155 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
The command '/bin/sh -c sudo apt-get install npm' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: You need to pass `-y` flag so apt installs packages automatically without user input. Also, it would be a good idea to group install commands together so it doesn't create unnecessary layers.

Comment: yes, by adding -y in apt-get install nodejs, related environment can be installed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04 
MAINTAINER Ke Peng <ke.peng@jingli365.com> 
RUN sudo apt-get update && \
    sudo apt-get install -y nodejs npm

WORKDIR /opt/app 

COPY . ./ 
RUN npm  install 
COPY dist/ /opt/app/ 
CMD node ./index.js < test.json
```

Answer (score 0):

**I would like to modify from this**:

```
RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN sudo -y apt-get install nodejs
RUN sudo -y apt-get install npm
```

**to this:**

```
RUN sudo apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs npm
```

and as whole it looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04 
MAINTAINER Ke Peng <ke.peng@jingli365.com> 
RUN sudo apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs npm
WORKDIR /opt/app 
COPY . ./ 
RUN npm  install 
COPY dist/ /opt/app/ 
CMD node ./index.js < test.json
```

As a [best practice](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#sort-multi-line-arguments) for Dockerfiles, **you need to build/install packages in a single layer.**

This will help the Image to be formed using minimal layers which will reduce the overall size of the Image.

Hope this helps.